# What does char c[2] = { [1] = 7 }; do?

Tags: c, arrays, initializer

I am reading [Bruce Dawson's article on porting Chromium to VC 2015](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2016/03/24/compiler-bugs-found-when-porting-chromium-to-vc-2015/), and he [encountered some C code that I don't understand](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2299303/internal-compiler-error-when-using-analyze-on-1-line-file?tduid=%28d4e0f345c67dadc7f8ed5bdbd11e5e66%29%28256380%29%282459594%29%28TnL5HPStwNw-EoyxhPZPofa9MPGg97So4Q%29%28%29).

The code is:

```
char c[2] = { [1] = 7 };
```

Bruce's only comment on it is: "I am not familiar with the array initialization syntax used - I assume it is some C-only construct."  So what does this syntax actually mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) allows you to specify the elements of the array in any order (this appears to be called "Designated Initializers" if you're searching for it). So this construct is assigning `7` to the second element of `c`.

This expression is equivalent to `char c[2] = {0, 7};` which does not save space for such a short initializer but is very helpful for larger sparse arrays.

See this page for more information:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html

Comment: It's equivalent to `char c[2] = {0, 7};` here but designated initializer is very convenient in the cases long arrays and structures.

Comment: That is another easy way to visualize, it. Added to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Its meaning would be

```
char c[2]={ 0, 7 }
```

OR you can say

```
char c[2];
c[0]=0;
c[1]=7;
```

Comment: Why `NULL`, that's a null ***pointer*** constant?! You want to use `0` or `'\0'` to initialise a `char`.

Comment: oh sry i meant 0x0 its nt NULL

Comment: Your second example is not an initializer but run-time statements.

Comment: it was to explain what it does